# ReturnType control Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I would like control the action of my `EditText` `ReturnType` how could I do something like this:

```
TextEdit user = new TextEdit();

user.ReturnType = ReturnType.Go;

Go.Clicked += (sender, e) => {
    //Login
};
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean the Xamarin Forms [Entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry#events-and-interactivity) control.  `Entry` has a `Completed` event that fires regardless of what the `ReturnType` is set to.

```
void Entry_Completed (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var text = ((Entry)sender).Text; //cast sender to access the properties of the Entry
}
```